# materialize dropdown click ignores options

Tags: javascript, materialize

I have following code to initialize materialize dropdown :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
        constrain_width: true,
        hover: false,
        belowOrigin: true,
        alignment: 'right'
    });
});
```

and following HTML:

```
<a class="dropdown-button" href = "#" data-activates = "management-menu-dropdown">
    Management<i class = "mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a>
<ul id="management-menu-dropdown" class="dropdown-content>
    <li><a href="/label_list">Manage labels</a></li>
</ul>
```

but whenever I click on `dropdown-button`, it seems that options are not applied (I'm specifically talking about `belowOrigin: true`). But when I set `hover: true`, all options seem to work fine, and if I hover the button and then click on it, the dropdown list again is not as expected. What is wrong here? tnx

Answer (score 0):

You missed the data-target attribute on anchor . Try adding this and see if it works.

```
data-target='management-menu-dropdown'
```

Check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwvxg8v7/1/) link

Comment: Its working in my fiddle, Can you check your console and let me know if you are getting any errors in that?